# Scale <img> to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area

Tags: html, css

This is like the `background-size: contain` property but I'm trying to do it with `<img>`. Is there any way to replicate it?

Comment: `width: 100%; height: 100%` or do you mean something else specifically?

Comment: @JiFus: that doesn't maintain the aspect ratio.

Comment: Well now I see what you mean. Then set the smallest (width/height) to 100% ?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670874/is-there-an-equivalent-to-background-size-cover-and-contain-for-image-elements

Comment: If you want to just use css,  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858994/css-media-query-height-greater-than-width-and-visa-versa-or-how-to-imitate-with

Comment: oh disregard, I misunderstood the question. JS is the way to go.